# How can I configure Cyrus IMAP to submit a default realm to SASL?

Tags: linux, email, configuration, authentication

I have configured Postfix to work with SASL using plain text, where the former automatically submits a default realm to the latter when requesting authentication.

Assuming the domain name is example.com and the user is foo, here is how I configured it on my Debian system so far.

In the postfix configuration file `/etc/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
```

The SMTP configuration file `/etc/postfix/smtpd.conf` contains:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: PLAIN
```

The SASL daemon is configured with the sasldb mechanism in `/etc/default/saslauthd`:

```
MECHANIMS="sasldb"
```

The SASL database file contains a single user, shown by `sasldblistusers2`:

```
foo@example.com: userPassword
```

The authentication works well without having to provide a realm, as postifx does that for me. However, I cannot find out how to tell the Cyrus IMAP daemon to do the same.

I created a user `cyrus` in my SASL database, which uses the realm of the host domain name, not `example.com`, for administrative purpose. I used this account to create a mailbox through `cyradm` for the user `foo`:

```
cm user.foo
```

IMAP is configured in `/etc/imapd.conf` this way:

```
allowplaintext: yes
sasl_minimum_layer: 0
sasl_pwcheck_method: saslauthd
sasl_mech_list: PLAIN
servername: mail.example.com
```

If I enable cross-realm authentication (`loginrealms: example.com`), trying to authenticate using `imtest` works with these options:

```
imtest -m login -a foo@example.com localhost
```

However, I would like to be able to authenticate without having to specify the realm, like this:

```
imtest -m login -a foo localhost
```

I thought that using `virtdomains` (setting it either to `userid` or `on`) and `defaultdomain: example.com` would do just that, but I cannot get to make it work.

I always end up with this error:

```
cyrus/imap[11012]: badlogin: localhost [127.0.0.1] plaintext foo SASL(-13): authentication failure: checkpass failed
```

What I understand is that `cyrus-imapd` never tries to submit the realm when trying to authenticate the user `foo`.

My question: how can I tell `cyrus-imapd` to send the domain name as the realm automatically?

Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some ancient discussions about adding this feature, but apparently there is no way to specify a default authentication realm.

Development of Cyrus IMAP has essentially been stalled for over a decade (1998-2002 was the last spurt of "significant" development). Yes, there are updates still done (the last was 19 Apr 2012 however, over a year ago).

I wouldn't hold my breath on this being added.

Comment: Humm, so I guess my choice is to either switch to another IMAP implementation or require the domain name to be specified in the username... Thanks for the reply.